# Java signal chaining

Tags: java, linux, signal-handling, sigchld, runtime-environment

I've got a program with a specialized `Process`-type class which handles executing the processes natively on Linux.

It does not use Java's [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class at all, because it needs to do some special handling of the process.  Because of this, it also installs its own signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, so that it knows when a process exits.

However, I just added a `Runtime.exec()` call in my code, which apparently installs its own signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, which means that I never get a `SIGCHLD` again, which is bad.  I've followed the signal-chaining instructions from [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/signal-chaining.html), but the same problem happens, I never get a `SIGCHLD`.

So, the basic question is this: is it possible to chain `SIGCHLD` in Java?

Comment: Which of the two described methods did you try?

Comment: Using `LD_PRELOAD`; I haven't tried making an application which embeds the JVM.

Comment: I will also award a BOUNTY of 100 to successful answer. (I cannot now as there can only be a single bounty to the question at a time)

Comment: Have you tried the `-Xrs` option to java ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`libjsig` does not help, because `SIGCHLD` handler is installed by `libjava`, not by JVM itself.

`sigaction(SIGCHLD, ...)` with sa_handler = `SIG_DFL` is called only once by Java Class Library in the static initializer of java.lang.UNIXProcess.

Now you have the following options to work-around this.

1. The easiest one. Just install your signal handler *after* initialization of `java.lang.UNIXProcess`.
2. Create your own `LD_PRELOAD` hook that will intercept `sigaction` and ignore it when called with `SIGCHLD` and `SIG_DFL` arguments:

E.g.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <signal.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction* act, struct sigaction* oldact) {
    static int (*real_sa)(int, const struct sigaction*, struct sigaction*) = NULL;

    if (signum == SIGCHLD && act->sa_handler == SIG_DFL) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (real_sa == NULL) {
        real_sa = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "sigaction");
    }
    return real_sa(signum, act, oldact);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How about using sockets to communicate with your child process in stead of SIGCHLD?
I assume you create the child process code yourself.